# Query : Folders within Self hosted agent in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops

I have a build pipeline created using a self hosted agent with source as GIT repo.
Within the build pipeline, I am using Copy files task with the source folder being 1 folder path within the GIT repo and target folder being : $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)/DF/

When I execute the pipeline and I login into the Self hosted agent , I observe the below set of folders:

[image]

where folder 2 and 3 are unique for each different pipeline (that is my guess )

And within the folder:

[image]

So van someone signify what does each folder which is autogenerated signify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number '1' '2'...'6' of work folder c:\work\1, c:\work\2...  in your build agent which stands for a particular pipeline.

> [Agent.BuildDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#agent-variables)
>
> The local path on the agent where all folders for **a given build
> pipeline are created**. This variable has the same value as
> Pipeline.Workspace. For example: /home/vsts/work/1

- `a` folder:

  The local path on the agent where any artifacts are copied to before
  being pushed to their destination. For example: c:\agent_work\1\a
- `b` folder:

  The local path on the agent you can use as an output folder for
  compiled binaries.

  By default, new build pipelines are not set up to clean this
  directory. You can define your build to clean it up on the Repository
  tab.

  For example: c:\agent_work\1\b
- `s` folder:

  The local path on the agent where your source code files are
  downloaded. For example: c:\agent_work\1\s
- `TestResult` folder:

  The local path on the agent where the test results are created. For
  example: c:\agent_work\1\TestResults

Comment: Hey , Thank you for the above details as it was very helpful.
I had 2 more queries:
1) Is it possible to auto clean up the S folder path
2) What does SourceRootMapping

Comment: 1) This is possible. [enable clean in the pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cVS09.png), 2)The source code is mapped to the `s` folder