# Azure Devops pipeline. Visual Studio Build or MSBuild steps: clean without a build

Tags: azure-devops, msbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-devops-server-2019

I have Azure Devops build pipeline and I want to add a step to it which will run a solution Clean task. I'd like to achieve the same behavior as when I press *Build->Clean Solution* in Visual Studio. The problem is that I haven't found how to do Clean only without a Build after. I looked through predefined build tasks (Visual Studio Build, MSBuild) without success.

How can I do this? I know that I can use a Command Line task to run MSBuild, but I wonder maybe I miss some straightforward solution.

Comment: Hi @scor4er, How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is an **Clean** option on the Get Source tab, which could perform different kinds of cleaning of the working directory of your private agent before the build is run:

[image]

We could set the value to `true` to clean the working directory of your private agent. Even if the build is failed.

You could check the document [Clean the local repo on the agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops#clean-the-local-repo-on-the-agent) for some more details.

If you are using YAML, you could try below script.

```
jobs:
- job: string  # name of the job (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
  ...
  workspace:
    clean: outputs | resources | all # what to clean up before the job runs
```

Check this document [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema) for some details.

**Update1**

The default work folder is `_work`, open it, we could see some folder `1,2,3...` such as below:

[image]

If you create a new pipeline, It will create a new folder under folder `_work`, each pipelines have their own work folder, the clean button just clean their work folder, it will not clean other work folder.

Comment: Unfortunately it won't work in my environment, there're multiple build directories and they contain many other files which I don't want to touch. It's crazy & wrong, but it is as it is.

Comment: Hi @scor4er, I have updated the answer, you could check the update1 and then kindly share the result here. In addition, you could also check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66686016/13903626) to get the work folder info

Comment: Sorry maybe I wasn't clear enough. I cannot clear output directory completely between the builds. It's not possible in my case. I build to a static path and the output folder remains on build agent between the builds, it contains a lot of bizarre junk from a lot of build steps, not only from a single Visual Studio solution. I only wanted to know the way to run Clean command for a single solution. Probably, I will just call MSBuild through a cmd directly. Thanks for your time anyway!